# R - Given a List of Vectors replace values in Vectors for each Vector with LOOP

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

Here is the set up. I have vec1 containing 5 numbers. I also have h5-h9 as a vector of 800 elements. The knot_list is a list of h5-h9 vectors containing 800 0's per h vector. Given x, I want to replace each h5,h6,h7,h8,h9's 800 elements with the formula x-(vec[i]) where i is 1:5 in this case.

```
vec1 <- c(1, 2, 3,4,5)
vec1 <- list(vec1) # needed for my real code
h5=rep(0,800);h6=h5;h7=h5;h8=h5;h9=h5
list_knot<- list(h5,h6,h7,h8,h9)
list_length <- length(list_knot) # 5 
x=seq(from=1,to=800,length.out=800)
```

Is there a way to make the formula described above replace each vector value in each element of the list? I tried doing for loops, but syntax is wrong.

```
for (i in 1:list_length){
  print(i)
  for (j in 1:length(seq(0,800))){
  list_knot[[i]][[j]] = x-vec1[[1]][[i]]^3
  }
 
}
```

The list_knot is set up where it is a list containing 5 vectors. Each vector has 800 0's that need to be replaced by the formula. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you unify your variable name in `list_knot[[i]][[j]] = x-list[[1]][[i]]^3`? Where `list_knot` and  `list[[1]][[i]]` come from?

Comment: Sorry, I just changed it. List_knot would be the list of h5,h6,h7,h8,h9 (5 vectors containing 800 0's) and list is simply vec1 in list form. list[[1]] refers to the vec1 within list and list[[1]][[i]] points to the element within vec1

Comment: It is not recommended to name your variables the same as R's native functions (`length` and `list` in this case).

Comment: Yeah you are right, if needed length variable can just be replaced with 5 and list can be renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that this is what you are looking for

```
vec1 <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) # as per your requirement
list_knot <- lapply(vec1[[1]], function(v, x) x - v^3, x = 1:800)
```

, i.e., subtract each element of `vec1` from the same `x` (1:800) and return a list of vectors. As you would like to replace every single element for each `h` in `list_knot`, you might just drop that list completely and construct a new one.

Comment: It worked with the sample code I ran.. Thank you so much. I will test it out on my actual code later. I need to remember lapply for the future.

Comment: It worked on my actual code too, thank you. I was wondering if you knew how to make all values within the list_knot that are less than zero = 0.

Comment: Change this `x - v^3` to `pmax(x - v^3, 0)` @chriswang123456